# Mapping rows in similar queries in object oriented way

Tags: java, oop, spring-jdbc

I have a question related to mapping a db data to domain objects in Java. I have to modify the existing logic and I would like to do it in a proper object oriented way.

I have an existing query which is really large. It consists of about 20 left joins. All columns (approximately 70) are mapped to a single flat POJO using an implementation of Spring's RowMapper. This POJO is immutable (so only getters are present) and has a nice (but huge) builder.

What I have to do is to add a second query which is very similar to the old one. The only difference is one different left join. So, both queries have about 60 common columns and only a few other which come from different left joins.

I would like to keep immutability here. Also, I need to have getters for all fields. So, I have two ideas:

1. Create a base object with all common fields. Then I may use an inheritance to create two different classes for different queries.
2. I can also use a composition to hold an object with all common fields. However, I need getter methods to access the state of this object. Here, I will need to implement a delegation for all getters what in my opinion is not a good idea, because I will have to copy-paste getters in all classes that contain my 'common' object by composition.

So, what is better? Or, maybe I should use something else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good question for this site(opinion based answers). user7294900's suggestion seems good to me and probably what I would've actually done in your place. Another option is to create completely separate classes, it feels like the correct solution but it creates additional overhead with little gain.

Comment: Yes, I have just accepted user7294900's answer. It seems to be the simplest solution to my problem. It is not a true object oriented approach. However, I will avoid an overhead of writing new POJOs with huge amount of accessor methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of first solution - Create a base object with all common fields, and use **Builder Pattern** to add extra columns as optional fields in Class, as:

```
optionalOne(String optionalOne) {
   this.optionalOne = optionalOne;
}
```